# Navigating around ul li and looking for the active state on the current slide

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How can I rewrite this in a simpler way?

```
$imageContainer = $($(this).parent().children()[0]).children()
currentIdx = 0
for e, idx in $imageContainer
  if e.className.indexOf('active')
    currentIdx = idx
    break
```

Comment: Could you describe what this code does?

Comment: Also we would like to know the context of `$(this)`

Comment: @Jamal Im navigating around ul li and looking the active state on the current slide (is a carousel)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for the index of the first child of `$imageContainer` with the `active` class. (Incidentally, your code will also trigger on stuff like `inactive`, which might be a false positive. Be careful about your classes!)

Native selectors work fine here. Furthermore, your initial assignment doesn't do things the jQuery way -- there's no reason to initialise two separate jQuery objects. Try replacing your block with something like:

```
$imageContainer = $(this).parent().children().first().children()
currentIdx = $imageContainer.index($imageContainer.filter(".active"))
```

Better yet, instead of that monstrous `.parent().children().first().children()`, give it a meaningful ID or class, so you can just do `$imageContainer = $(".image-container", this)`.

If you can guarantee that the `ul` will contain *only* `li`s, then you can simplify further to `currentIdx = $imageContainer.filter(".active").index()`.

Depending on your exact situation, you may even be able to replace everything with the one liner:

```
currentIdx = $(this).parent().find(".active").index()
```